# ESP32 / C++ File Download as String

Tags: c++, arduino, download, esp32

*Reposting a question because it has been wrongfully banned (See P.S.)*

I have an **file download server** (Calling it *myfilesserver.xyz*) **using http** (not https) and I want to **download a file from it**. In python I have a simple 2 line code snippet that does just that (See below). But **in C++** on my ESP32 I can't just do it with an HTTP request, **it returns an empty response**.

I haven't found an solution on google, does anyone know a (compact preferred) way to **download a file** and read it's **content as an String**?

Python Code

```
import requests
x = requests.get("http://fileserver/release/file.bin")
```

P.S. I already am using a library for that, its the HTTPClient that comes bundled with most Arduinos. I'm not seeking for a new one. I want to know whether or not it is possible to do with this one.

I'm not going to trim the code before posting it here because last time I did I got told not to. If I'm wrong with that, please tell me.

The code I'm currently using:

```
void update(String repoUrl) {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(repoUrl);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      payload = http.getString().substring(22);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Wrong HTTP Response: " + httpCode);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wrong HTTP Response: " + httpCode);
    return;
  }

  http.begin(payload);
  httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      payload = http.getString().substring(22);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Wrong HTTP Response: " + httpCode);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wrong HTTP Response: " + httpCode);
    return;
  }
  if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)){
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS!");
    return;
  }
  File fileWrite = SPIFFS.open("/update.bin", FILE_WRITE);
  if(!fileWrite){
    Serial.println("An error has occured while opening the file for writing!");
    return;
  }
  String fw = http.getString();
  Serial.println(fw);
  fileWrite.print(fw);
  Serial.println("File should be written, size is " + fileWrite.size());
  fileWrite.close();
  
  File fileRead = SPIFFS.open("/update.bin");
  if (fileRead) {
    if(fileRead.isDirectory()){
      Serial.println("Error, update.bin is not a file");
      fileRead.close();
      return;
  }
  size_t fileSize = fileRead.size();
  if (fileSize > 0) {
    Serial.println("Try to start update");
    if (Update.begin(fileSize)) {      
      size_t written = Update.writeStream(fileRead);
      if (written == fileSize) {
        Serial.println("Written : " + String(written) + " successfully");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Written only : " + String(written) + "/" + String(fileSize) + ". Retry?");
      }
      if (Update.end()) {
        Serial.println("OTA done!");
        if (Update.isFinished()) {
          Serial.println("Update successfully completed. Rebooting.");
        } else {
          Serial.println("Update not finished? Something went wrong!");
        }
      } else {
        Serial.println("Error Occurred. Error #: " + String(Update.getError()));
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not enough space to begin OTA");
    }
  } else {
      Serial.println("Error, file is empty");
  }
  fileRead.close();
  
  // when finished remove the binary from sd card to indicate end of the process
    SPIFFS.remove("/update.bin");      
  } else {
    Serial.println("Could not load update.bin from sd root");
  }

}
```

Comment: You should add more detail.  It's not really clear what the problem is.  You say you had an empty response.  Was there an error code?  What was the code?  You say you run the HTTP server yourself.  What is shown in its logs?  What exactly is it serving?  Is it an actual text file?  Your URL suggests it might be binary data, which is unsuitable for strings in C++ because in a string, a `char` with the value `'\0'` is interpreted as the end of string.  If you're receiving binary data, you must store it in an appropriate container such as a vector of bytes.

Comment: the HTTPClient libraries are different. for esp32 see the StreamHttpClient example